# Gender-neutral equivalent of "to a man"

Tags: idioms, synonyms, gender-neutral

Is there a Gender-neutral equivalent of "to a man"?

I mean the expression "to a man" in the sense of "each and every one".

For example:

> The skydivers, to a man, felt they had taken all necessary precautions

Is there a similar expression that would be a good substitute without implying a gender?

Comment: I've heard something like "they were in agreement *to a man and a woman*". It is probably what I would use.

Comment: Each and every skydiver...

Comment: @Mari-LouA yes, but that isn't quite an equivalent sentence construction, so not really a direct substitute. Perhaps you could say "the skydivers, each and every one, felt..." its just not as concise

Comment: @WS2 But that's not gender neutral, you have specificed two genders instead of just one, and it's more verbose

Comment: You eliminate "man" from the equation but the problem remains, because no matter how much we might aspire to gender neutral language, it's a fact that whenever we hear or read "skydiver" or "firefighter" or "General" or "steel worker" or even "President" we think of "man".

Comment: Nothing wrong with "To a person".

Comment: @DJClayworth I haven't heard that before but actually I think its the smoothest replacement suggested to far.

Comment: “one and all”. . .

Answer (score 5):

Well, the [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-thesaurus/to-a-man) offers you some alternatives

- without exception
- each and every one
- one and all